# IIS express not running MVC site , not creating site in applicationhost.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

Im trying to run a MVC project created by another developer. I copied his project locally to my computer and ran the site. It compiles fine but IE displays page cant be displayed •Make sure the web address http://localhost:xxxx is correct 
this site deployed to IIS on our uat server just fine but it wont run local with IIS express.

Looking at the   applicationhost.config file  there are no entries for this projects site.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? When you copied the files over, did you check .vs folder? Which `applicationHost.config` did you look at?

Comment: visual studio 2015 and the applicationHost.config in IISs \Documents\IISExpress\config folder. What would I check in th .vs folder?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/04/29/new-asp-net-features-and-fixes-in-visual-studio-2015-rc.aspx

Comment: deleting the applicationHost.config in the vs folder did the trick thanks